# Need to add google autocomplete box in multiple input

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I need to add google autocomplete suggestion on multiple input in array.

Here is my sample code:

```
<mat-form-field *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3,4,5]" class="example-full-width form-controlNew">
  <input matInput autocomplete="off" placeholder="17 Summit Avenue" formControlName="formattedAddress" #search>
</mat-form-field>
```

app.component.ts

```
/// <reference types="@types/googlemaps" />
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  NgZone,
  ElementRef,
  ViewChild
} from "@angular/core";

private geocoder;
@ViewChild("search")
public searchElementRef: ElementRef;


ngOnInit() {
setTimeout(() => {
  this.setCurrentPosition();
  this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
    const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      this.searchElementRef.nativeElement,
      {
        types: ["location"]
      }
    );
    this.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
      this.ngZone.run(() => {
        const place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry === null) {
          return;
        }
        this.lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
        this.lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
        this.quickjobform.patchValue({
          location: {
            formattedAddress: place.formatted_address,
            zipcode: this.getAddressComponent(place, "postal_code", "long"),
            city_sector: this.getAddressComponent(
              place,
              "sublocality_level_1",
              "long"
            ),
            city: this.getAddressComponent(place, "locality", "long"),
            country: this.getAddressComponent(place, "country", "long"),
            latitude: this.lat,
            longitude: this.lng
          }
        });
        this.zoom = 8;
      });
    });
  });
},5000);
}
```

I got this error

> TypeError: Unable to get property 'nativeElement' of undefined or null
>   reference TypeError: Unable to get property 'nativeElement' of
>   undefined or null reference at

Please check and help me.

Comment: Not sure about the syntax and implementation but have a look at [here](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)

Comment: and you can access the element in `ngAfterViewInit()` life hook cycle!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale i have checked and got same result.

Answer (score 2):

You have to access the element in `ngAfterViewInit()` life cycle hook which implements the `AfterViewInit` interface

```
// Import this
import {Component, Directive, Input, ViewChild,AfterViewInit,ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

export class Your_Class implements AfterViewInit {
@ViewChild("search") public searchElementRef: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.searchElementRef); // do whatever with element
  }
}
```

[Working Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kuddey-fuqojw)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ViewChildren` here. You render your `#search` thing in a `*ngFor` repeater - which means there are multiple of those, so Angular can't decide which one you want. So you do this with a `ViewChildren` instead, like this:

```
@ViewChildren('search') searchButtons; // these are your search things.
```

[Here's](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-view-children-examples?file=src/app/app.component.html) an example that illustrates some issues here.

Comment: Actually it chooses one, this is not what causes the TypeError. However, in this case, ViewChildren is a better option than ViewChild

Comment: Yeah well, close enough :)

Comment: @Zlatko i am using viewChildren and i got this error `14597 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined`